# How to generate Access Token for Azure with grant type password? PowerBI REST API

Tags: azure, powerbi, powerbi-rest-api, azure-oauth, azure-oauth2

I want to be able to get access tokens automatically without the need of user interaction (that is manually typing the credentials in an OAuth pop-out).
I'm using grant_type: password for this; however, I'm getting an invalid_grant error, saying the credentials are wrong but the credentials are correct since I can use them to login to the Azure platform.

I used Postman for this, with the tenant, client_id, and basic scopes shown in the Azure platform.
POST: [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenant}}/oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7B%7Btenant%7D%7D/oauth2/v2.0/token)
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Body:

```
client_id={{client_id}}
&client_secret={{client_secret}}
&scope=User.Read
&grant_type=password
&username={{user@name.com}}
&password={{password}}
```

Do you have any ideas as to what could be causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

The error usually occurs if you are using **external user** credentials in ROPC flow to generate access token.

As mentioned in this [MS Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc),

> The Microsoft identity platform only supports the ROPC grant within Azure AD tenants, not personal accounts. Personal accounts that are invited to an Azure AD tenant can't use the ROPC flow.

I registered one Azure AD application and added `User.Read` API permission as below:

[image]

When I tried to generate access token using ROPC flow by including **external user** credentials, I got same error as you like below:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id: <appID> 
client_secret:<secret>
scope:User.Read
grant_type:password
username:demouser_gmail.com#EXT#@xxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com
password:xxxxxxxxx
```

**Response:**

[image]

To resolve the error, you need to change  `username`  and  `password`  with  **local**  Azure AD user credentials like below:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id: <appID> 
client_secret:<secret>
scope:User.Read
grant_type:password
username:sri@xxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com
password:xxxxxxxxx
```

**Response:**

[image]

But the above token won't work to call Power Bi as `User.Read` is Microsoft Graph permission. You need to add **Power Bi** permissions in your application to call Power Bi REST API like below:

[image]

While generating access token, make sure to change **scope** to https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default like this:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id: <appID> 
client_secret:<secret>
scope: https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default
grant_type:password
username:sri@xxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com
password:xxxxxxxxx
```

**Response:**

[image]

You can verify it by decoding the token in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms/) that have **`aud`** and **`scp`** claims as below:

[image]